# Implementing text editor functions, getting individual node elements, getting the cursor position

Tags: javascript, dom, nodes

I am just a beginner in JS and I am working on a text editor. Below is a sample code. I need to make some details similar to MO Word,
it’s hard for me to explain what I specifically need, but visually I attached a video in which at least a little, but showed what I needed
https://youtu.be/QXAMFLs9QPM

1. The editor button must be active and display the active style when clicking on the element (word),
   accordingly, when the cursor switches to another element (word), the button loses its active style
   and you need to click again to perform an action on the element (left), so the button becomes active,
   but at the same time, for previous elements, if you put the cursor on them, the active style of the button is preserved.

As I understand it, there is work with the node, but I don’t know how to get the individual elements (words) of the node, and not the node itself (string) as a whole
and there is still a problem with how to find out the position of the cursor?

2. it is necessary to get the result from the button, provided that the cursor is placed on the word, and not only when the text is selected
3. Selecting an entire line of text on a click condition

I will be grateful for any help

```js
function formatDoc(cmd, value = null) {
    if (value) {
        document.execCommand(cmd, false, value);
    } else {
        document.execCommand(cmd);
    }
}

function toggleClass(el) {
    if (el.className == "btn") {
        el.className = "active";
    } else {
        el.className = "btn";
    }
}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap");
* {
    margin: 0;
    /* padding: 0; */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

li {
    margin-left: 16px;
}

.container {
    /* max-width: 991px; */
    width: 625px;
    background: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: solid 1px lightgray;
}

.toolbar {
    padding: 16px;
    background: #eee;
}

.toolbar .head {
    display: flex;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.toolbar .btn-toolbar {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    grid-gap: 10px;
}

.btn {
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.active {
    background: #b6d3f1;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.toolbar .btn-toolbar button:hover {
    background: #f3f3f3;
}

#content {
    padding: 16px;
    outline: none;
    max-height: 50vh;
    overflow: auto;
}

#show-code[data-active="true"] {
    background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.9/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>Text Editor</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="toolbar">
            <div class="btn-toolbar">
                <button class="btn" onclick="formatDoc('bold'), toggleClass(this)">
            <i class="bx bx-bold"></i>
          </button>
                <button class="btn" onclick="formatDoc('underline'), toggleClass(this)">
            <i class="bx bx-underline"></i>
          </button>
                <button class="btn" onclick="formatDoc('italic'), toggleClass(this)">
            <i class="bx bx-italic"></i>
          </button>
                <button class="btn" onclick="formatDoc('strikeThrough'), toggleClass(this)">
            <i class="bx bx-strikethrough"></i>
          </button>
                <button class="btn" onclick="formatDoc('justifyLeft'), toggleClass(this)">
            <i class="bx bx-align-left"></i>
          </button>
                <button class="btn" onclick="formatDoc('justifyCenter'), toggleClass(this)">
            <i class="bx bx-align-middle"></i>
          </button>
                <button class="btn" onclick="formatDoc('justifyRight'), toggleClass(this)">
            <i class="bx bx-align-right"></i>
          </button>
                <button class="btn" onclick="formatDoc('justifyFull'), toggleClass(this)">
            <i class="bx bx-align-justify"></i>
          </button>
                <button class="btn" onclick="formatDoc('insertOrderedList'), toggleClass(this)">
            <i class="bx bx-list-ol"></i>
          </button>
                <button class="btn" onclick="formatDoc('insertUnorderedList'), toggleClass(this)">
            <i class="bx bx-list-ul"></i>
          </button>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
            in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2pdf.js/0.10.1/html2pdf.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha512-GsLlZN/3F2ErC5ifS5QtgpiJtWd43JWSuIgh7mbzZ8zBps+dvLusV+eNQATqgA/HdeKFVgA5v3S/cIrLF7QnIg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</body>

</html>
```